# how could i forbid a tableviewcell to be selected

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

As usual, when a tableviewcell is touched, it will be selected. But now i need one cell in my tableview never be selected.how could i forbid a tableviewcell to be selected?

After modifying didSelectRowForIndexPath: method. It works now. Thx ALl:)
Once the cell (need to be forbidden) is selected i just use the selectRowAtIndexPath method to select the former selected cell to be selected again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didSelectRowForIndexPath:` method, you can check if the cell meets your quality standards and accordingly, show a `UIAlertView` or go ahead if it meets the requirements

Comment: Yes, i modified didSelectRowForIndexPath: method. It works now. thx:) Once the cell (need to be forbidden) is selected i just use the selectRowAtIndexPath method to select the former selected cell to be selected again.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to use [`tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW13).
Unlike all the other answers this will work with segues too ;-)

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath should not be selected) {
        // if another indexPath should be selected instead return this indexPath
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: Is this related to segues? It seems doesn't work, don't know why. But tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: is really a useful method, thx:)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the user Interaction for that very cell or set the selection Style None for that cell. Hope that helps!

Comment: if the user interaction is disabled, the switch in that cell could not response to my touch.

Answer (score 1):

In your `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method add the following line to the cell you want to be not selectable:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

And in your `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method add the following at the beginning:

```
if (indexPath == indexPathOfTheCellThatShouldntBeSelected) return;
```

Comment: the cell still can be selected, but just without any style. thank you all the same:)

Comment: @luyuan please take a look at the edit part. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: not yet:), i just fixed the problem, and added the solution in my post:)